# Need for generating XmlSerializers assemblies when using WCF and Data Contract Serializer

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751883.aspx) describes how to improve startup time for WCF client applications by pre-generating serialization code for assemblies by the use of `svcutil.exe` (or `sgen.exe`). However, it only mentions improving performance for serialization/deserialization using `XmlSerializer`.

The default serializer for WCF is `DataContractSerializer`, and my question is: for a WCF client talking only to WCF services, is there any advantage of generating the **.XmlSerializers.dll* assemblies? The only source of information I could find regarding this specific question, was [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5a3cda5f-1b42-44eb-ae45-77d41f302231/wcf-client-slow-to-startif-using-datacontractserializer-does-xmlserializer-pregen-help?forum=wcf) on MSDN. The answer given may suggest that generating `XmlSerializers` only affects serialization by `XmlSerializer`, but it doesn't say clearly.

Answer (score 0):

From [Using the XmlSerializer class MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx), section "Security Considerations":

> Another threat that exists whenever you use XmlSerializer is related to write access to the system temporary folder. The XmlSerializer serialization engine creates and uses temporary serialization assemblies in this folder.

This is mentioned in contract with `DataContractSerializer` so generating `*.XmlSerializers.dll` doesn't seem to have any value when using `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: Though you might be correct, but the article doesn't clearly states that default DataContractSerializer doesn't use the Serialized assembly.

Comment: True. The simplest assumption is that it doesn't and this assumption is supported by experiments that I've conducted.

Comment: Does DataContractSerializer use any temp assemblies for Serialization/Deserialization like XMLSerializer, have you read anything about this ?